# Regex find string and replace that line and following lines

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, find

I am trying to find a regex to achieve the following criteria which I need to use in javascript.

Input file

> some string is here and above this line
>   :62M:C111111EUR1211498,00
>   :20:0000/11111000000
>   :25:1111111111
>   :28C:00001/00002
>   :60M:C170926EUR1211498,06
>   :61:1710050926C167,XXNCHKXXXXX 11111//111111/111111

Output has to be

> some string is here and above this line
>   :61:1710050926C167,XXNCHKXXXXX 11111//111111/111111

Briefly, find :62M: and then replace (and delete) the lines starting with :62M: followed by lines starting with :20:, :25:, :28c: and :60M:.

Or, find :62M: and replace (and delete) until the line starting with :61:.

Each line has fixed length of 80 characters followed by newline (CR LF).

Is this really possible with regex? 
I know how to find a string and replace the same line where the string is. But here multiple lines to be removed which is quite hard for me.

Please could someone help me out if it is possible with regex.

Comment: This article should help: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. First I'm finding text to delete using regex (note that I'm using `[^]*` to match all the lines insted of `.*`, as it also matches newlines). Then I'm replacing it with a newline.

```js
var regex = /:62M:.*([^]*):61:.*/;
var text = `some string is here and above this line
:62M:C111111EUR1211498,00
:20:0000/11111000000
:25:1111111111
:28C:00001/00002
:60M:C170926EUR1211498,06
:61:1710050926C167,XXNCHKXXXXX 11111//111111/111111`;

var textToDelete = regex.exec(text)[1];
var result = text.replace(textToDelete, '\n');

console.log(result);
```